# Tricking the CLT

Tags: probability-theory

I am looking for a sequence of i.i.d. RVs $X_{n}$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$, a standard normal RV $X$ and a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $n$ we have $P(\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k} \in A) = 1$ but 
$P(X \in A)=0$.

By Portmanteau, obviously we need $P(X \in \partial{A})>0$.

So my idea was to choose $A=\mathbb{Q}$ and each $X_{n}$ with values in the rationals, but I can´t find a specific construction that also ensures independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(X_1 = 1)=P(X_1=-1)=1/2$ (this is the Rademacher distribution). This has mean $0$ and variance $1$. Now let
$$A:= \{a/\sqrt{b}: a\in \mathbb{Z}, b\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$
Then $A$ is countable, since $|A|\leq |\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}|$ and the latter is countable. It is clear that $\sum_{k=1}^nX_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ a.s. for any $n.$ Hence for any $n$,
$$P\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\in A\right) = 1.$$
However, since $A$ is countable, $P(X\in A)=0$.